Is ἴκελος ever attested with the genitive in place of the dative
This question arises from Sappho LP 96 lines 5-6, which are lines 4-5 of its source parchment, and, in the source, read:
Ϲ€Θ€Α . ΙΚ€ΛΑΝΑΡΙ
Γ . ωΤΑϹΑΙΔ€ΜΑΛΙϹΤ̣€ΧΑΙΡΕΜΟΛΠΑΙ̣
The ending is pretty clearly σᾷ δὲ μάλιστ̣' ἔχαιρε μόλπᾳ. For the rest, I have seen several options:

-σε θέα‹ι› σ̣' ἰκέλαν Ἀρι- / γν̣ώτα (Campbell and others);
σὲ θέα‹ι› ϝ̣ικέλαν ἀρι- / γν̣ώτα‹ι› (Edmonds);
σὲ θέας̣ ἰκέλαν ἀρι- / γν̣ώτα‹ς› (mentioned by Voigt);
σὲ θέα‹ι›σ̣' ἰκέλαν Ἀρι- / γν̣ώτα.

I tried to argue for 2, saying that the uncertain sigma could possibly be the bottom of a digamma, and that maybe the parchment just omits adscript iotas, but then you have the certain ϹΑΙ, so that's a no-go, and thus 2 is the one that requires the most corrections.
1 is probably the safest option, but it requires a correction nonetheless, and one that doesn't seem to have any sort of analogue in the parchment (more on that later). It is also incompatible with the integration by Edmonds to the beginning, which I (almost) accepted on two different occasions, and also translated into Sicilian (see here), and I'd really like not to have to change that. The same can be said about 4.
The no-correction option would mean the θέα ἀριγνώτα considered the lost addressee of the poem, or whoever the σὲ could be, equal to herself, so basically the goddess was with Sappho and whoever else this poem is about, which is probably indefensible. And it also would change the beginning, so that's another no-go.
Option 3 seems appetizing. Only one correction, just like one, but would be the same as 2 in meaning, and there are two more examples of double letters being simplified in this parchment, namely περ‹ρ›έχοισ' & ἀ δ' ἐ‹έ›ρσα a few lines down: "haplography", if you will. The problem is, ἴκελος with the genitive is news to me. Is it ever attested thus? I consulted my dictionary, and it doesn't say anything but dative. LSJ just won't load for me.
What do you think of this?
For the sake of completeness, here is Voigt's apparatus on this passage:

'inc. quomodo dividendum corrigendumque sit' LP; maxime placet σὲ (Schub., Wil.) θέα‹ι›σ' (Wil. apud Schub.1, θέ‹οι›σ' Maas '24, 1008 conl. S. 68a, 3) ἰκ. Ἀρίγνωτα (sc. vocat.: Wil. adscr. Pfeiffer '26, 316, ita Milne '34, 202) vel γνώτα (Dl. SL1), possis etiam -σε (L.); θέα‹ι› (Blass) σ' ἰκ. ἀριγνώτα‹ι› (Edm.1) L. (θέας ... ἀριγνώτα‹ς› Reinach, Z.); nuper disput. Marz., Maia 5, 1952, 85ss.; 'ad Ἀ. cf. Ἀριγνώτην filiam (?) Pythagoræ (Page falso neg. hoc nom. propr. esse)' Snell


I cross-posted this to Quora, seen as no answers were coming in here, and Nick Nicholas posted the following answer, which I cross-post as agreed with him.

I don’t have access to the TLG, Michele, even if I implemented the morphological analysis and the search engine that made a search for ἴκελος in all cases on the TLG feasible to begin with.
Never said life was fair.
I’ll just tell you what the open Internet says, which is not that much:

LSJ records the genitive instance of ikelos, “similar of a god”, and adds that the passage is dubious; everywhere else it knows of, as you say, it’s dative. ἴκελος (LSJ)
Neither LSJ nor DGE refer to any instance of eikelos “similar”, the more common form of the adjective, with a genitive: εἴκελος (LSJ)
homoios “similar”, the more common Ancient word for “similar”, is always used with the dative in the poets before Sappho, and usually in the Greek after Sappho; but LSJ does note occasional use of the genitive (ὅμοιος (LSJ), B 2).
But significantly, all the instances in Classical Greek are either variant readings (so either the authors didn’t write them, or the authors did write them but scribes corrected them to the dative, and we don’t know what was which), or else implied instances because of elliptical constructions, which makes them weak evidence. The first unambiguous instance LSJ gives of a genitive with homoios is as late as Dionysius of Halicarnassus. And that’s late.

So, is the genitive in “equal of a goddess” suspect in Sappho? Yeah, it’s suspect: the tendency to use a genitive in “similar of” is late, and its attestation in Herodotus and Plato questionable. Not impossible, I guess, but suspect. Which is why people have proposed emendations to correct it in Sappho.
And I see from the Googles that at least one reading rejects the genitive, and thinks the -s in theā-s is actually s’ “to you”:

Lyric and Greek Myth | Short Writings: I. Table of Contents Lyric and Greek Myth Gregory Nagy


echen se theās ikelan arignōtā<s> “held you equal of a well-known goddess” (what the papyrus says)
echen se theā<i> s’ ikelan arignōtā<i> “held you equal, you, to a well-known goddess” (the reading Nagy replicates, whoever came up with it)

That reading is… odd.
From Tedeschi’s recent edition of Sappho, that seems to have fallen off the back of a truck online, I see that a similar reading which preserves the dative has been proposed by Max Treu in his 1968 edition of Sappho, and he compares it to Iliad III 158, Odyssey VI 107. It makes a bit more sense the way he proposes it:



echen se theā<i>s’ ikelan, Arignōtā “held you equal to the goddesses, O Arignota” (Anacreon fr. 72 uses Arignota as a proper name)

As you can see, editors of Classical texts can be ingenious in
resolving odd-looking texts they find handed down.
As you can see, they have to be.

